# How do I get the $variables defined in Livewire controller into my blade file?

Tags: html, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

In my blade file, I have a syntax that goes like

```
@if($variable)
@endif
```

but I get an error that says "Undefined variable #variable". This variable is already defined in my Livewire controller, however, I am using a different controller for the blade file that calls this variable. Is there any way to call the defined variable from my blade file? A senior told me to "move the livewire blade line into your respective newly created blade file." but I couldn't quite understand and he's too busy to explain, so can anyone help me to figure out how fix this?

Comment: @if($variable)
@endif

Comment: @Abdulmajeed oh i just corrected the question thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

Simply said; no you can't access the variable if it's defined in a different controller/component.

If a variable is defined in a Livewire component, then it will only be available in the Livewire linked view (and potential included parts/components). If it's defined in a Laravel controller, then it's only available in that linked view. You can pass variables from Laravel to Livewire, but not the other way around. If a variable is not defined in Livewire, it won't be available in the linked view.

Your senior probably told you to move the line from your Laravel view to the Livewire view (as that is where you set the variable).